# Display ICollection values in one column

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't display values in grid from ICollection. I use this lib http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/.

I tried to create a cycle to iterate through ICollection but it didn't work

```cs
//Model
public partial class CsoSupport {
public CsoSupport()
{
CsoSupportMonitoring = new HashSet<CsoSupportMonitoring>();
}
public string ExpectedResult { get; set; }
public ICollection<CsoSupportMonitoring> CsoSupportMonitoring { get; set; }
}

//View
@(Html.Grid(Model.csoFinancialSupportModel).Build(columns =>
{
columns.Add(model => model.ExpectedResult).Titled("ExpectedResult"); //works
columns.Add(model => model.CsoSupportMonitoring).Titled("Date");  //not working
}
```

I want to display dates from model.csoSupportMonitoring

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a property specifically for display? And do something like the following.

```
        //Class
        public partial class CsoSupport {

        public CsoSupport()
        {
           CsoSupportMonitoring = new HashSet<CsoSupportMonitoring>();
        }

        public string ExpectedResult { get; set; }

        public string CsoSupportMonitoringDates { 

         get {

             return string.Join(",", CsoSupportMonitoring.Dates):   
          } 

        }

        public ICollection<CsoSupportMonitoring> CsoSupportMonitoring { get; set; }
        }



    //View
    @(Html.Grid(Model.csoFinancialSupportModel).Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(model => model.ExpectedResult).Titled("ExpectedResult");
        columns.Add(model => model.CsoSupportMonitoringDates).Titled("Date");
    }
```